# Component Position (Vaadin)

Tags: java, image, liferay, portlet, vaadin

I have a simple portlet with a few components : 3 `Button` objects, 1 `Slider`, 1 `MenuBar` and a picture assigned to a `Label` (generated by servlet). Now when I switch between pictures for a `Label` (I have more of them), I want the picture `Label` to be placed at the old picture `Label` object's position:

My picture `Label` is in the left corner of the portlet. The `Button` objects, `MenuBar`, and the `Slider` are under the picture `Label` when I select another picture `Label` the new picture `Label` is being drawn under the other components (under the `Button` objects , `MenuBar` , `Slider` ) so the `Button` objects... are top and the picture `Label` is at the bottom  of the portlet

for example, I change the background of the picture `Label` by selecting the color in the menu :

```
newItem1.addItem("Blue",new Command(){
    public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem){
        if(pictureA.isVisible()){
            pictureB.setVisible(false);
            pictureC.setVisible(false);
            window.removeComponent(pictureA);
            pictureA= new Label("<img src=http://localhost:8888/portlet/KiviatDiagramm?background=blue", Label.CONTENT_XHTML);
            window.addComponent(pictureA);
        } else {
            window.showNotification("", Notification.TYPE_WARNING_MESSAGE);

        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE :**

I have switched from `Label` objects to embedded images (`Embedded`) (which is a lot better) I have tried to reassign the resource on the `Embedded` object with the new color but it doesn't work, here is what I've done :

```
public void init() {

    URL PictureAUrl= null;
    try {
        pictureAUrl= new URL("http://localhost:8888/portlet/pictureA");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URL PictureBUrl= null;
    try {
        pictureAUrl= new URL("http://localhost:8888/portlet/pictureB");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URL pictureCUrl= null;
    try {
        pictureCUrl= new URL("http://localhost:8888/portlet/pictureC");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final Embedded pictureA = new Embedded("", new ExternalResource(pictureAURL));
    pictureA .setType(Embedded.TYPE_IMAGE);
    final Embedded pictureB = new Embedded("", new ExternalResource(pictureBURL));
    pictureB .setType(Embedded.TYPE_IMAGE);
    final Embedded pictureC = new Embedded("", new ExternalResource(pictureCURL));
    pictureC .setType(Embedded.TYPE_IMAGE);


    newItem.addItem("ColorBlue", new Command(){
            public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
                if(!pictureA.equals(pictureB )){

        Resource newPictureResource = new ExternalResource("http://localhost:8888/portlet/pictureA?background=blue");
        newPictureResource.setType(Embedded.TYPE_IMAGE);
        pictureA.setResource(newPictureResource);

                }
                else {
                    window.showNotification("Please select pictureA");
                }
        }
   });
```

Comment: Instead of removing pictureA, can't you reassign the `src` of the existing `<img>` to the new picture's URL?

Comment: @miq and Paul Grime  i have updated the question please look in to it maybe you see what i dont

Comment: What happens when you load the image URL directly in a browser? Do you see the image/colour you expect?

Comment: i cant even compile it : Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method setResource(Resource) is undefined for the type Embedded

Comment: You should probably have that in the question then, that you can't compile the code. People viewing the question aren't mind readers! Does your IDE not tell you there is no setResource method? Have you read the Javadoc? - http://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Embedded.html#setSource%28com.vaadin.terminal.Resource%29

Comment: setSource() works (as long as i remove     newPictureResource.setType(Embedded.TYPE_IMAGE);
 thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rickthomas is correct, you should use the replaceComponent method. I'm pretty sure that the main problem here is that after you have removed the picture, you call addComponent(pictureA) which actually adds the component to the end of the component list. If you don't have a reference to the old picture and it's the first component, then you can use this:

```
window.replaceComponent(window.getComponentIterator().next(), newPicture);
```

In addition to that, you don't have to write HTML to show images. You can use [Embedded](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.embedded.html).

If the images are in your classpath, you can use the following:

```
Embedded newPicture = new Embedded("", new ClassResource("my-picture.png", myApplication));
newPicture.setType(Embedded.TYPE_IMAGE);
window.replaceComponent(oldPicture, newPicture);
```

If they are found somewhere else, use this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8888/portlet/KiviatDiagramm?background=blue");
Embedded newPicture = new Embedded("", new ExternalResource(url));
newPicture.setType(Embedded.TYPE_IMAGE);
window.replaceComponent(oldPicture, newPicture);
```

This might solve your problem.

Comment: a little problem : now when i select the same color multiple time the picture is being placed multiple times witout the old pictue being removed .

Comment: I guess you could surround the replaceComponent call with if(!newComponent.equals(oldComponent)) { // replace code here } so that you don't replace the component with itself

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Vaadin API javadoc,

I found this

```
public void replaceComponent(Component oldComponent,Component newComponent)
```

I haven't tested it... but it should work.